# I think recursion will solve this; but I'm not sure how?

Tags: recursion

I'm creating a UI. Right now I'm working on generic `box`s that dynamically add and remove scrollbars as they are resized.

I draw the scrollbars along the bottom and right inside edge. The inside edge is important.

So at some point the box is resized. If it's resized I check to see if the new size is smaller than the size needed for the contents, if so, scroll bars are added.

My problem stems from when only one scrollbar is needed; and the size for the other dimensions/axis is very close to the size needed for the contents.

What happens is that this scrollbar is drawn on the inside edge. Now that removes area that can be used for the contents. The problem is then that if a scrollbar is shown I would have to check the area available again to see if the other scrollbar is needed. And then again.

This seems like a recursive problem; but I'm not sure how it will help me.

Some code:

```
void Box::UpdateVisibleRegion()
{
    // if the dimensions of this box is smaller than what the widget needs, display horizontal scrollbar
    if(GetDimensions().x < m_widget->GetDimensions().x)
    {
        m_scrollbarH->SetVisibility(true);
        m_scrollbarH->SetSize(utils::coord<int>(GetDimensions().x,m_scrollbarH->GetDimensions().y));
    }
    else
    {
        m_scrollbarH->SetVisibility(false);
    }

    // likewise for vertical scrollbar
    if(GetDimensions().y < m_widget->GetDimensions().y)
    {
        m_scrollbarV->SetVisibility(true);
        m_scrollbarV->SetSize(utils::coord<int>(m_scrollbarV->GetDimensions().x,GetDimensions().y));
    }
    else
    {
        m_scrollbarV->SetVisibility(false);
    }
```

And there's the problem. If the height of the box is just over the widgets height; and the width is far under it; then the horizontal scrollbar is displayed. But now the check for vertical scroll bar should have been:

```
    if(GetDimensions().y - m_scrollbarH->GetDimensions().y < m_widget->GetDimensions().y)
```

Because the scrollbar is drawn on the inside edge, there's less room. But obviously I can't know that until I've checked the other. And both the horizontal and vertical are going to affect each other.

I'm sure recursion is the answer; but I can't see it.

I could probably do this with one or two big nested if statements...

Comment: Please work on your presentation. What language is the code in? Which GUI framework are you using? Please edit the question, add suitable tags, consider changing to a more descriptive title which mentions your actual problem. Thanks.

Comment: You need **3 things** for a recursive function. **(1)** logic within the function that sets the conditions for the recursive call, **(2)** the recursive call within the function, and **(3)** a way to terminate the recursion and either **return a value** or **effect the desired changes** outside of the scope of the function. In your case your function sets visibility. You want to call the function again if it has changed dimensions/visibility in some way. Having the function return a value or set a global flag indication whether a condition changed may provide an exit test.